# How to download Weblogic Adapter in Eclipse Luna SR1

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic

I'm trying to download Weblogic Adapter for Eclipse Luna SR1.

Everytime I download a new version of eclipse I just go to the "Download additional server adapters" link to shows a list of available adapters and select the weblogic adapter.

Now that Eclipse Luna SR1 was released I can't find the weblogic adapter. The glassfish adapter that is usually in the list here is not listed neither.

What Happen to Oracle adapters? How can I install this adapter if is not in the list of adapters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the adapter you are looking for through the Eclipse Marketplace (see Help -> Eclipse Marketplace). Search for "Oracle WebLogic Server Tools for Luna".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the whole oracle Enterprise stack, go to the market place and install "Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse (OEPE)".
I was looking for a question and got better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the eclipse built with the adapter by Oracle.

Eclipse Luna + Weblogic Plugin:
[http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/oepe-12131-2228123.html][1]